# Лишний Insert уже существующего объекта в БД (Postgresql)

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

Есть приложение *WPF* (паттерн *MVVM*) с двумя окнами (Авторизация и главное окно...).

- Для *MVVM* использую *SimpleMvvmToolkit* из *NuGet*.
- Для соединения с *Postgresql* использую *Npgsql*(который зависит от *Entity Framework*).

Если пользователь вводит правильно логин и пароль, я передаю **объект** *User*(со всеми данными) в новое окно. В свою очередь в новом окне, этот объект сохраняется в свойство:

```
public User User
{
    get { return _user; }
    set
    {
        _user = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.User);
    }
}
```

**NotifyPropertyChanged** — метод из *SimpleMvvmToolkit*.

И тепер главная проблема. 
Когда я пытаюсь сохранить любые данные(даже другие модели) методом *db.SaveChanges()*, первым делом проходит запрос в БД на Insert этого же User(тот что записан в свойством). И конечно я ловлю Exception, что уже такой пользователь существует.

Надеюсь понятно объяснил ситуацию. Могу еще какие-то куски кода скинуть, если это поможет решить проблему.
Спасибо

Comment: не надо слов, покажите код, с которым у вас проблемы.

Comment: Сущность, полученную в другом экземпляре контекста, необходимо приаттачить к новому экземпляру, иначе он будет пытаться ее вставить и получать ошибку о нарушении уникальности, что у вас и происходит.

Comment: @АндрейNOP
Большое спасибо, это действительно помогло. Опубликуйте ваш комментарий в ответы... Я переделал весь код на использование только одного экземпляра контекста

Comment: Опубликуйте то что у вас заработало самостоятельно. У меня не на чем проверить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня в методах, где нужно было изменить какие-то данные в БД, использовался новый экземпляр контекста, это и стало причиной появления данной ошибки. Первым делом я объявил контекст *лишь один раз*, чтобы далее его использовать в методах.

Ну и чтобы убрать ошибку, я теперь передаю из окна авторизации на главное окно не только **объект** *User*, но и уже созданный экземпляр контекста

Главная причина данного явления, это что новый экземпляр контекста пытался вставить уже существующую сущность, так как эта сущность была получена в другом контексте

*Контекст -- это класс, производный от DbContext*

Comment: *Первым делом я объявил контекст лишь один раз* - эээ, я вам писал что надо приаттачить сущность к новому экземпляру контекста, а не переходить к единому экземпляру. Вы выбрали не лучшее решение

Comment: @АндрейNOP
Знаю, но у меня реализован CRUD, и в каждом методе был использован новый контекст

Comment: ну и что, что мешает в вашу фабрику, создающую вам экземпляры контекста, добавить одну строчку: `context.Users.Attach(user);`?

Comment: Окей, попробую сделать так